# Check if a volume (.ply) contains a 3D-point

Tags: python, volume, point-clouds, pyvista

I'm looking for a solution to define if a given 3D-point is contained in a volume (defined by a polygon .ply file).

I use **PyVista** to define my volume from a point cloud.

But I do not understand how to manipulate the PLY volume, there is vertices and faces.

I would like to get something like this :

`volume.contains(point)` which will return true or false

My first idea was to create a sphere for the point to substract/intersect it with the volume, but i'm not sure about that.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I won't post a full answer because there are some ambiguities about the details of your question, but you can take the intersection of meshes, see https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/01-filter/extract-cells-inside-surface.html. Especially the line `select = mesh.select_enclosed_points(rot)` should be of interest to you. I don't know if that method accepts raw arrays too, but at worst you can probably build a simple mesh that contains your points of interest.

Answer (score 1):

This was eventually solved here:
https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista-support/issues/349

Solution was to simply compute the distance between the generated mesh and the original mesh with:

```py
dist = shell.points - point
```

Please see the issue for more details.

Comment: Ahah yes thank you, I am the author of the question on GitHub ! Have a nice day !